# Perform further processing on rule value in Less

Tags: css, less

I have multiple icons and am trying to derive a generic way to use any of them as a "button" - which I'm defining as the exact same as the icon with a little bit of extra surrounding space.

- Since this is to be a clickable element I'm using padding instead of margin for the extra space.
- Since the icon uses a sprite, I'm having to use `background-clip: content-box` so I don't pick up any other images from the sprite
- I know I could add a wrapping element as a work around but would not like to since this is an existing site with legacy content I don't want to restructure to that degree.

  ```
  @pad: 6px;
  .iconA {
      background-image: url("sprite.png");
      background-position: -100px -50px;
  }

  .iconAButton {
      background-clip: content-box; 
      padding: @pad;
      &:extend(.icon-minus);
      background-position: getRule(.iconA, 'background-position-x') + @pad
          getRule(.iconA, 'background-position-y') + @pad;
  }
  ```

The most feasible solution I can see is declare two variables, e.g. `@iconAOffsetX` and `@iconAOffsetY` and use the variables in both `.iconA` and `.iconAButton` but this isn't a very scalable solution.

Comment: Well, what you want ("reading ruleset property values") is eventually planned to be added in Less, however it does not look like the proper solution for the use-case (you're are not going to repeat all this code for every of your 100 icons, are you?). What you really need there is to learn and use [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature). Mixins *is* the key to generic and reusable code.

Comment: For [example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/13c2d7ed2fc546654b60#file-35511679-md).

Comment: Honestly I didn't think that far out. I was just going to add the __button classes as I needed them (only need one so far), but you're right - if I'm going to enhance this your example is more reusable than assuming the .iconA is perfect and refusing to enhance that code. If you put your comment and example in an answer I'll mark it resolved.